# Problems in glmnet package

Tags: r, machine-learning, glmnet

I have a problem with the following codes.

```
ridge.mod=glmnet(x,y,alpha=0,lambda=grid)
```

The glmnet function is a function contained in the "glmnet package".

When I run this code, it displays the following error.

```
Error in elnet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, type.gaussian,  : 
  could not find function "elnet"
```

What is causing this error?
The "elnet" function is a function that is also embedded it the glmnet package.

Comment: remove glmnet (as in delete the folder for the package) and install again. If this does not help update post with your `Sys.info()`.